# How to create a random number that doesn't repeat?

Tags: c++

I have a variable that will either become 1 or 0, and all I know is `rand()% 2`.

The problem is when I loop it it keeps becoming either 1 for about four times straight then 0, or 0 for straight 6 times then 1.

I want it to be like 0 for once or twice, then 1, then 0 again. Something like that.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: ... so you do not want it to be random?

Comment: Runs of consecutive 1s or 0s are exactly what you'd expect some of the time...

Comment: If you believe it isn't random enough, you could try taking bits from the higher positions, for example `(rand()>>24)&1`. The old algorithms (like rand) were known to have better randomness at high-order bits than low-order (and the new ones may suffer from this too, I'm not sure). But you'll still get runs of numbers; it's inevitable (1 in 8 chance of a consecutive run of 4 0s or 1s from a perfectly random source)

Comment: @EdHeal: To be fair, it would still be random, just no longer uncorrelated.

Comment: Anybody have a link to that site where you try to generate random numbers yourself (by clicking heads and tails) and the computer tries to predict them, showing how nonrandom you are?

Comment: instead of using `rand()%2` I think you can use [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) where you can input the limits for your random number

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to have only runs of 1 or 2, while maintaining some randomness, you can keep track of it like this;

```
int nextRandomIshThing( ) {
    static int n1 = 0;
    static int n2 = -1;
    if( n1 != n2 ) {
        n1 = n2;
        // use a high-order bit, which supposedly has better randomness
        // 14 because the standard guarantees that rand() produces at least
        // 15 bits of randomness (not sure why that exactly)
        n2 = (rand( ) >> 14) & 1;
    } else {
        n2 = !n2;
    }
    return n2;
}
```

http://codepad.org/HTTtPezu

But beware that depending on how you're using this, it means that users can "game" your system; "I've seen 2 1's, therefore the next *must* be 0!". A truly random source will always produce long sequences. There is a 1 in 8 chance for a truly random source to produce 4 1's or 0's in a row, and a 1 in 16 chance of 5. When you consider that you don't care where exactly the run starts, this becomes even more likely. If you want to be fair, embrace this instead of fighting it!

Oh and don't forget to `srand`.

Comment: Either this solution directly or add some weighting that makes equal results following each other less likely (but still possible).

Comment: @Till yes that would be the better solution, but if he's just looking for something which will look cool for an "information flowing" picture (which is what I suspect), this is a lot easier!

Answer (score 3):

You either want a random number or a predictable result. You can't choose the amount of randomness, the whole point of a random number generator is to generate something unpredictable.

But what you can do is simply use the random number in a different way. If you want, say, at most, 4 consecutive runs of 0 or 1 you could determine the count of consecutive numbers using `rand` and generate the numbers yourself:

```
int number = 0;
for (int runs = 0; runs < 100; ++runs) {
    int count = rand() % 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < (count ? count : 1); ++i) { // Ensure at least 1 run
        printf("%d", number);
    }
    number = 1 - number;
}
```

See codepad example:
http://codepad.org/OKe5Agib